# Guaranteed Atomic Operations on POD types naturally aligned on Intel

Tags: c++, multithreading, x86, atomic, memory-alignment

I have a C++ multi-thread applications running on Intel Xeon 32 cores, compiled with GCC 4.8.2 with optimizations enabled.

I have multiple threads (say A,B,C) that update some POD types, and another thread D that every K seconds reads those variables and send it to a GUI. The threads are spawn across multiple cores and sockets. The writes are protected by a spin-lock. Thread A,B,C are latency sensitive where high performance is a critical aspect. Thread D is not latency sensitive.

Something like:

```
Thread A,B,C
...
// a,b,c are up to 64 bits (let's say double)
spin-lock
a = computeValue();
b = computeValue();
c = computeValue();
spin-unlock
....

Thread D
...
// a,b,c are up to 64 bits (let's say double)
currValueA = a;
currValueB = b;
currValueC = c;
sendToGui(currValueA ,currValueB ,currValueC );
....
```

I want to take advantage of Paragraph 8.1.1 https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-vol-3a-part-1-manual.html, about guaranteed atomic operations, and avoid to put a lock protecting the reads made by thread D.

My understanding is that if a,b,c are naturally aligned (with a size no bigger that 64 bits) there is no risk that Thread D could read a value for a,b,c that is taken halfway during the write. In other words the writes and reads will be carried out atomically. The thread D will read either the old value or the new.

Is my understanding correct?

I left to the compiler GCC 4.8.2 to take care of the alignment, i.e. I don't use any gcc built-in directives or functions like std::alignas, sts::alignof, etc.

I am aware that the code is not portable.
I would prefer not to use std::atomic to avoid any unnecessary overhead.

Comment: with `std::atomic` and specify target architecture, compiler might do the optimization by itself. So your code would be portable. let compiler job to compiler.

Comment: Have you found any "unnecessary overhead" caused by the use of `std::atomic`?

Comment: Using `std::atomic` with `memory_order_relaxed` won't have any overhead at all for pure loads and pure stores (and will ensure correct alignment for 64-bit values even in 32-bit code, where `alignof(int64_t)=4` on Linux), but it will interfere with auto-vectorization.  (Avoid using any atomic RMW operations, of course).  If you care about performance, consider using a newer compiler, like gcc7 or gcc8.  There have been various improvements since 4.8.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I compared the assemblies generated with an atomic store (memory_relaxed and target specified) and a normal assignment. They look a bit different. I see two more instructions: movabsq and movq. I can't say though if they have any impact on performance. I should also definitely try out the newer g++. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to program "to the metal" using the Intel spec, are you going to use inline assembly?

Comment: @curiousguy No it's not my intention to use assembly. Are you implying that, unless a developer doesn't inline assembly, it's not a good idea to program "to the metal"?

Comment: If you don't use assembly, you are programming in C/C++ not to the metal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading a value "taken halfway during the write" is only one aspect of atomicity.

Processors these days keep values in processor-specific caches, so on a multi-processor system, two different processors may well have different values for the `a` that they share. Marking `a` as atomic ensures that different processors see "the same" value.

In addition, the compiler and the processor often reorder calculations in order to make better use of processing facilities. That's all okay, so long as the **result** of those calculations isn't changed. (That's the "as if" rule in C++). But "isn't changed" refers to execution within a single thread. Optimizations that work in a single thread don't necessarily work when multiple threads are pounding on the same object. And you don't, in general, want your single-threaded code to be compiled by a paranoid compiler that doesn't do common optimizations because they might break multi-threaded code. Instead, marking an object as atomic says that the compiler should be very careful about what things it moves around, because that object's value can be changed behind the scenes by some other code.

So you have a choice: hand-roll your code and hope that you get it right, or accept that the writer of the `atomic` library probably knows more about atomicity on your target system that you do, and will probably do a better job.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. If I understood the re-order correct, it is not really an issue for my situation. If the latency threads execute the a,b,c assignment in a different order than I wrote it's okay. It is also okay if the GUI shows b and c updated while a is not. It is also okay that the Gui doesn't show the very latest value for the variables. But I get your concerns. Without atomic It's not a well-defined behavior. Thanks.

Comment: Your 2nd paragraph describes the right C++ symptom, but it's not cache that causes the issue.  Multi-CPU systems use coherent caches, so anything that's stored to memory is visible by other cores as soon as it commits to your own L1d cache. (And `std::atomic` default to `mo_seq_cst`, which also block StoreLoad reordering.)  The issue is that data-race UB allows compilers to optimize non-atomic variables into registers.  e.g. `while(!val){}` compiles to asm like  `if(!val) infinite_loop();` [MCU programming - C++ O2 optimization breaks while loop](//electronics.stackexchange.com/a/387478)

Comment: @MCU -- **SOME** Multi-CPU systems use coherent caches. Some don't.

Comment: Can you point to an example of a real multi-core system that can actually run multiple C++ threads of the same process across non-coherent shared memory domains, requiring explicit flushes of everything in any mutex unlock or release-store?  Also note that this was tagged `[intel]` (corrected to `[x86]`), and all x86 systems are cache-coherent.  If you built a non-coherent x86-like system using x86 CPUs, you'd need a special compiler for it because it wouldn't follow the x86 memory model.  See also [Is mov + mfence safe on NUMA?](//stackoverflow.com/a/54653446)

Comment: The C++11 memory model assumes cache coherency, because a release store synchronizing with an acquire load makes it ok to read *any* non-atomic data that was written before the release store.  So if explicit flushes are needed, everything that could possibly be part of a sychronizes-with relationship needs to do explicit flushes / syncs on *all* memory.  Or more likely the implementation would add functions to sync certain addresses or ranges of addresses, because syncing everything would defeat half the purpose of non-coherent caches..